# The chiral ring of N=2 WZW models

Tags: string-theory

Does anyone knows if the chiral ring of the Kazama-Suzuki models have been found? If yes, please send me the reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Lerche, Vafa, Warner 1989, Nuclear Physics B,

> http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~anderl/lgcft/1989%20--%20Lerche,%20Vafa,%20Warner%20--%20Chiral%20Rings%20in%20N=2%20Superconformal%20Theories.pdf